# How to Git-Ignore Symlinks on a Magento Module installed by composer

Tags: composer, git

I install modules using `composer.phar`.

This creates symlinks files in `publichtml/app/code/community` (for example) with a target to `vendor/themodule...`.

In my `.gitignore` I excluded the vendor directory - but the links would of course still end up in the git.

Is there an *easy* way to automically exclude those links? (other than adding everything manually to the .gitignore)

I have to say that I have some `require-dev` modules which should not end up on the final server - so having those links there would be at least not so nice.

Comment: Would this apply to modman, too?

Comment: With modman you generally would use git submodules for each extension and simply add the symlinks to the repository. No need to exclude them there, on the contrary, it wouldn't make sense in a modman deploy scenario mostly.

Comment: @philwinkle I recently started tracking the Magento root  in a separate repo for security reasons (e.g. easily detect modified files), to track changes to index.php and Mage.php, and for easier Magento upgrades so definitely relevant for modman as well, IMO.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best I came up with was running this after an composer install/update

```
$ find * -type l -not -exec grep -q "^{}$" .gitignore \; -print >> .gitignore
```

The command should be run in the git root directory. It adds all symlinks to the .gitignore file that aren't in there already.

Comment: this generates path's like `./foo/bar` .. I think we have to remove the first `.` - did it work for you like that?

Comment: Works fine for me with the leading ```.```, yes. Else sed to the rescue: ```find . -type l -not -exec grep -q "{}" .gitignore \; -print | sed 's/^\.\///'```

Comment: Actually, that breaks the grep... well, maybe there is a good way to clean the path up anyway...

Comment: Simple solution: ```find * ...```. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This method only adds untracked symlinks so can be repeated without adding duplicate entries, symlinks that are in submodules or are otherwise already ignored, or intentionally tracked symlinks.

```
for f in $(git status --porcelain | grep '^??' | sed 's/^?? //'); do
    test -L "$f" && echo $f >> .gitignore;
    test -d "$f" && echo $f\* >> .gitignore;
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays there is an option for this in the composer installer. Just set extra.auto-add-files-to-gitignore   https://github.com/magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer/blob/master/README.md#auto-add-files-to-gitignore

Answer (score 1):

The combined solution of @ColinM and @Vinai that works for me

```
for f in $(git status --porcelain | grep '^??' | sed 's/^?? //'); do
    if test -L "$f"
    then
        test -L "$f" && echo $f >> .gitignore;
    elif test -d "$f"
    then
        find ${f%/} -type l -not -exec grep -q "^{}$" .gitignore \; -print >> .gitignore
    fi
done
```

Comment: Did you notice that recent composer installers auto exclude the symlinks?

Comment: Sure, but some of my projects is not under composer control. And solutions provided here are not only for composer projects but for ignoring symlinks altogether. Hope it will help somebody